# Keeping aspect ratio of image in full screen

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to put together a webpage which consists of the following (top to bottom):

- image/background-image (full screen width, keeping aspect ratio)
- navigation bar (on top of image, right aligned)
- some text
- another full screen image (same as the first)
- footer

The issue I'm having is that if I use background-image I have to specify the image height in px. If I use img instead I can only seem to get this working (with the navigation bar on top) using absolute positing which in turn doesn't allow me to place the second div's below the first.

Apologies for the quickly put together image, I hope it shows what I'm aiming to do.

[image]

Comment: where is your html and css code? and are you using cover for the background image in the css?

Comment: use absolute position on the header where the nav and logo is ... not absolute for the img container ...

Comment: mlegg - I keep attempting to add my code but someone edits my question and doesn't allow me to re-save.

Comment: DaniP - Will this still be responsive if I try this?

Comment: yes you can do it responsive ... that way

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t4t5z85e/ quick example

Comment: DaniP - that's exactly what I'm after, thank you :) would mark as correct if I could

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the use of the `img` tag what you need to do is position your "header" elements over the content with `absolute` position not position `absolute` the img's container:

```css
header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 255, .5);
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}
div img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>Logo & Nav</header>
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/500" alt="">
</div>
<div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem quam, temporibus tenetur qui, sed magni. Praesentium, veritatis perferendis qui? Et accusantium, dicta natus libero iste atque voluptatem est. Dolore, consectetur.</div>
  <div>Eius obcaecati itaque assumenda fuga quam necessitatibus nam consectetur ab velit nostrum minus maxime ex temporibus autem iure, rem ea nihil totam sapiente perferendis praesentium ullam labore amet corrupti! Numquam!</div>
  <div>Esse accusantium excepturi sint deserunt praesentium repellat eius quibusdam ratione hic, modi blanditiis numquam tempore iusto, nisi dolore! Autem quis cumque mollitia atque perspiciatis vero animi eius quidem itaque enim.</div>
  <div>Deleniti magni ipsum illum odio, rerum ullam praesentium expedita vel impedit vitae ad eveniet voluptatem reiciendis reprehenderit omnis doloremque cumque assumenda, eligendi quas cupiditate sed numquam facere porro accusantium! Aliquam!</div>
  <div>Expedita nisi excepturi repudiandae quod provident animi numquam consequatur quidem, magnam non optio, saepe autem laudantium quis perferendis beatae veniam, quae assumenda deleniti eius cupiditate. Est, beatae deserunt facere magnam.</div>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't have to specify a fixed height for your background-image. If you specify only its width and the height stays auto, it will retain its original dimensions

```
.background-image {
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Comment: you will need to specify the height of the container in order to show the entire background image ... so fixed height or to responsive behavior use the padding trick.

Comment: @DaniP The op might have this request, but from what I've read I'm simply not sure if he wants that or simply the background-image not to be stretched when resizing the browser...

Comment: Apologies if I've not explained well but I am after with DaniP has explained.

Answer (score 1):

To implement the setup you've presented above, there is a way to use background-position and still have it retain its dimensions. The text overlaid on top will need to be absolutely positioned, so that's a decision you'll need to make. Here's the set-up for the top image section, in this case acting as if the image has a 16:9 aspect:

```
.background-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  background: url('someimg.jpg') center center / no-repeat cover;
}
```

Padding bottom percentage is based on the viewport's width, so this would mean the height is 56.25% of the 100% width, or 16:9. Let me know if you have any questions about the implementation there.

Answer (score -1):

```
.className {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Adding this code seems to fit the image to the screen height which doesn't keep the aspect ratio

Comment: // Force a ratio of 5:1 for all <div>
  .viewportRatio(5, 1);

Comment: // Mixin for ratio dimensions    
.viewportRatio(@x, @y) {
  width: 100vw;
  height: @y * 100vw / @x;
  max-width: @x / @y * 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

div {

  // Force a ratio of 5:1 for all <div>
  .viewportRatio(5, 1);

  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}

Comment: This solution will cause huge issues with content outside of that top container, and pulling content from normal document flow is not a great idea unless absolutely necessary (here it's not).

Comment: arun - I'm not keen on the idea of forcing the ratio. Thank you for your help though :)